# How do I bind a 1D array to a 2D display (datagrid or gird) in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpf-controls

I'm trying to set up databinding of a usercontrol. I have an item source List, its length is 64, I want to display it in 8x8 grids instead of 1x64 list because there is not enough room to display in UI. How to do that in WPF?

Comment: add your xaml or we cant help..

Answer (score 0):

If they should all be the same size, then I would recommend using a [`UniformGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid). Here's an example of how you would use a `UniformGrid` in an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="...">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="8" Columns="8" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

You should be able to substitute `ItemsControl` for any of its descendants, such as `ListBox`.

If `UniformGrid` isn't exactly what you're looking for, my second suggestion would be [`WrapPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel). That should get you roughly the layout you want, but it wouldn't be a fixed 8x8 grid.

If neither of those panels work for you, I think the only remaining option would be to build your own.